# Крайне  (НЕ)профессионально  и (не)этично

Tags: орфография

Здравствуйте! Задумалась над слитным/раздельным написанием данных слов. По правилам вроде бы нужно писать слитно. Но как быть со словом "крайне"? Не выступает ли оно здесь в роли усилительной (aвтокорректор заменил на "умилительной"))) частицы и не ослабляет ли связь между НЕ и последующими словами? (т.е. возможно ли раздельное написание?) Спасибо!

Comment: Спасибо всем за ответы. Я только не поняла, мне на почту пришло соообщение, что был еще ответ Людмилы, но я его что-то не вижу...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильно: крайне непрофессионально и неэтично.

КРАЙНЕ - это наречие со значением сильного проявления признака, оно, действительно, выступает в роли усилительного слова, но усиливает утвердительный характер выражения.

Близкие по значению слова: очень, чрезвычайно, абсолютно.